# What is the issue with this simple Swift function builder example?

Tags: swift, function-builder

I'm trying to experiment with function builders in XCode 11 and constructed this simple playground. It doesn't seem to be using the function builder to convert the input into the desired resultant closure, but I feel like I must be missing the point somewhere. The reported error on the last line is `cannot convert value of type '(Int, Int)' to closure result type 'Scene'`

```
import SpriteKit

public protocol Scene {
    var width   : Int {get}
    var height  : Int {get}
}

public struct EmptyScene : Scene {
    public let width : Int
    public let height: Int
}

@_functionBuilder public struct SceneBuilder {
    public static func buildBlock(_ size:(Int,Int))->Scene {
        return EmptyScene(width: size.0, height: size.1)
    }
}

extension SKScene {
    public convenience init(@SceneBuilder _ scene :  () -> Scene){
        let definition = scene()
        self.init(size: CGSize(width: definition.width, height: definition.height))
    }
}

SKScene {
    (320,256)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're missing a step. I think about function builders as being an annotation I have to add to a function, so the annotated function has a nicer call site (just some values inside of curly brackets, which can aid in quick composition/grokking). I don't know much about SpriteKit but the compiler was happy with this:

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import SpriteKit

import SpriteKit

public protocol Scene {
    var width   : Int {get}
    var height  : Int {get}
}

public struct EmptyScene : Scene {
    public let width : Int
    public let height: Int
}

@_functionBuilder public struct SceneBuilder {
    public static func buildBlock(_ size:(Int,Int))->Scene {
        return EmptyScene(width: size.0, height: size.1)
    }
}

extension SKScene {
    public convenience init(@SceneBuilder _ scene :  () -> Scene){
        let definition = scene()
        self.init(size: CGSize(width: definition.width, height: definition.height))
    }
}

*here*

@SceneBuilder
func buildDaScene() -> Scene { (320, 256) }

SKScene { buildDaScene() }
```

Comment: Thank you very much.... I'm not sure that's the right right answer... Looking at the SwiftUI code I can't see an equivalent of of `buildDaScene`. My understanding (quite possibly wrong) was essentially this is what `buildBlock` is equivalent to. However, for now your edit keeps me moving forward  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's a Swift bug: single-expression closures are not considered in function builders. (See [here](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-11628), although it's not clear which Swift version resolves it.)

I added another `buildBlock` method which takes multiple tuples (and ignores all but the first), and sure enough, it works.

```swift
@_functionBuilder public struct SceneBuilder {

// no difference whether or not we keep the old buildBlock as well
    public static func buildBlock(_ size: (Int,Int)...) ->  Scene {
        return EmptyScene(width: size[0].0, height: size[0].1)
    }
}

SKScene {
    (320,256)
} // won't compile

SKScene {
    (320,256)
    (321,257)
} // creates one SKScene with (320,256)
```

In any case, passing a single-expression closure to a function is exactly the use case where you *don't* need function builders, and this works just as expected:

```swift
extension SKScene {
    public convenience init(_ tupleClosure: () -> (Int,Int)){
        self.init(size: CGSize(width: tupleClosure().0, height: tupleClosure().1))
    }
}

SKScene {
    (320, 256)
} // creates the scene
```

Function builders are needed in cases where you want to process all of the subsequent expressions in a closure, something that wasn't possible before the introduction of this feature.

So the good news is that you already know how to construct them (well, already knew in November :) ), and they should work with multiple expressions… and the fix already exists for single expressions (and there's also a workaround for those).